How to calculate this multiple intrgral？
Let us define $D = \{(x,y): 0\leqslant x \leqslant 1, 0\leqslant y \leqslant 0.5\}$, compute
$$
I = \iint_{D} \exp(4x^{2}y^{2}-x^{2}-4y^{2}) \sqrt{1-x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y
$$
I tried to make substitution:
$$
\begin{cases}
u = 1-x^2 \\
v = 1-4y^2
\end{cases}, \dfrac{D(x,y)}{D(u,v)}
$$
But then I can't continue the calculation.

After your $u$-substitution, the integral at least becomes separable in $u$ and $y$ and can be reduced to a $1$-variable integral in $u$, but I can't reduce it further (has some complicated terms involving err functions). You may want to show your steps after $u$-substitution for others to pick up from there
